# multidimensional arrays and function calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to work with a multi-dimensional in the following way

```
function 2darray(mynum) {
  var outarray[];

  outarray.push(1, 3, 5);
  outarray.push(2, 4, 6);

  var inarray[];

  for (var i = 0; i < outarray.length; i++) {
    inarray.push(outarray[i]);
  }
```

// now i want to pass info to another function

```
  getmyarray(inarray[mynum])
}


function getmyarray(access) {
```

// and access the passed values here, but am i doing the following correctly, and what do i put where the ?'s are..

```
  xassess = access[ ? ][0];
  yassess = access[ ? ][1];
}
```

Comment: You need to firstly correct your syntax errors with this line `outarray.push([1, 3, 5)];` and the following one. People will be reluctant to help you if your code contains simple syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are no multi dimensional arrays in Javascript, so what you have is an array of arrays, also known as a jagged array.

Just omit the second index, and you will send the inner array to the function:

```
getmyarray(inarray[mynum]);
```

In the function you have a plain array of numbers, so just access it by a single index:

```
xassess = access[0];
yassess = access[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no traditional multidimensional arrays in javascript, only arrays of arrays.

```
// a literal array
var my2dArray = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
];

// a "constructed" array
var my2dArray = [];
my2dArray.push([1, 2, 3]);
my2dArray[1] = [4, 5, 6];
my2dArray[2] = [];
my2dArray[2][0] = 7;
```

Accessing a 2D array is pretty plainforward too; it just works like a 1D array returning another array.

```
my2dArray[0] == [1, 2, 3];
my2dArray[0][0] == 1;
my2dArray[0][1] == 2;
my2dArray[1][2] == 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks bart!!

```
var my2dArray =[
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6]
];
```

works great! and when i pass it into a function

```
getmyarray(my2darray[mynum])
```

i can access like you would expect!

```
function getmyarray(mypassedarray)
{    var x=mypassedarray[0];
```

and console.log(x); is correct!

..now i'm not sure why,but when i try to use the passed values in the google earth plug-in i get
"error: error calling method on npobject" and that error comes on the range part...investigation in progress..